# Visual Studio: filter out certain folder from 'Navigate To..' feature

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a Node.js project inside Visual Studio 2013 and whenever I use the *Navigate To* feature (`Ctrl + ,`) it searches through all the 3rd party code in `node_modules` folder (there are usually hundreds of files there).

Is there a way to filter out some folders from the *Navigate To* feature?